# How to schedule tasks in Microsoft Bot Framework + C#?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, bots, botframework

I am building a test bot using Microsoft's Bot Framework / Bot Builder for C#.NET / LUIS. It is deployed on Azure. The idea for my test project is to send a reminder to the user.

For example, when the user asks "remind me in two hours to buy milk", it should initiate a conversation or send a reply to the existing conversation in two hours.

I have no problem parsing natural language into date and task using LUIS, however I have no idea how to schedule a task so that the framework would somehow send a reply to the user later on.

I've read the docs and checked the examples at https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/, and also searched on StackOverflow, but it seems that the framework doesn't support it. I've also looked at Azure Scheduler, but it seems insanely expensive, even if my bot would only have 100 users with one scheduled task each.

What is another way to schedule tasks so that the bot sends a message to the user at an appointed time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, your question involves two parts:

**1. How to start a conversation**

In v3.0, MS introduced a new way to start a new conversation (group or 1-on-1). Reference: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html#conversation

Sample code:

```
var connector = new ConnectorClient(incomingMessage.ServiceUrl);
var ConversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(incomingMessage.Recipient, incomingMessage.From);
IMessageActivity message =  Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.From = botChannelAccount;
message.Recipient = new ChannelAccount() { name: "Larry", "id":"@UV357341"};
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: ConversationId.Id);
message.Text = "Hello";
message.Locale = "en-Us";
var reply = await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(message);
```

**2. How to schedule a job**

There are multiple ways of doing it, you can use an external queue service, Azure web jobs, web roles, or try to register in the ASP.NET itself.

**Hangfire** (http://hangfire.io/) is what I'm using for my bot.

Code sample:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(
() => TriggerConversation(), // <= the start conversation code here
TimeSpan.FromDays(1)); // <= when the job should be ran
```

Comment: Are you using free version or payed?

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran: I'm using free version

Comment: Can you give a demo of how to do it?

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran: my code is as simple as the one in my answer, what problem are you facing?

Comment: Am looking to start up my bot on a specific time to a specific user. is that possible using this?

Comment: I did install hangfire, but confused where to all this startup and registering things.
The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
 - No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
 - No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Quartz.NET seems to be a popular solution for scheduling tasks. It can store them in a database in Azure.

Comment: Would be great if you provide the implementation