# MS Bot Framework (Nodejs): Session lifetime and delayed messages

Tags: botframework

This is my first try with Bot Framework (Nodejs). I want to test delayed messages, for example, my bot must answer after a 5 seconds after receiving the message.
So I tried with this code:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var connector = new builder.consoleconnector().listen();
var bot = new builder.universalbot(connector);

bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    if (!session.userData.TimeoutStarted) {
        session.send("I'll answer in 5 seconds");
        session.userData.TimeoutStarted = true;

        setTimeout(function() {
            session.send("Answer after 5 seconds");
            session.userData.TimeoutStarted = false;
        }, 5000);
    } else {
        session.send("Bot is busy");
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work. Callback function inside setTimeout fires, but all operations with session doesn't work at all.

So, I find possible solution here: [How to send message later in bot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434723/how-to-send-message-later-in-bot-framework/38442365#38442365) and rewrite my code:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    if (session.userData.Timeout > 0 && Date.now() - session.userData.Timeout > 5000)
        session.userData.Timeout = 0;

    if (!session.userData.Timeout) {
        session.send("I'll answer in 5 seconds");

        var reply = session.message;

        setTimeout(function() {
           reply.text = "Answer after 5 seconds";
           bot.send(reply);
        }, 5000);

        session.userData.Timeout = Date.now();
    } else {
        session.send("Bot is busy");
    }
});
```

This code works, but looks terrible with so many checks. So I have a few questions:

1. Why first code example doesn't work? I guess problem in the session lifetime and then what is session lifetime?
2. How to set session.userData in this examples? So In first code example I want to set it inside callback function inside setTimeout but it doesn't work too.
3. What is the best way to create delayed answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just investigated this issue. Looks like there's a bug in `ConsoleConnector` that makes it impossible to send two messages using the same `session` object (above a given interval between messages, due to internal batching). As the state is also persisted during `send`, your delayed state update will also not work. If you added a call to `session.save` to your callback in `setTimeout`, it would persist the new state (but would still not send the message).

I believe your first example should work with `ChatConnector` (haven't had the chance to try though). I'll create a pull request with the fix to `ConsoleConnector`.

I hope this answers all your questions.

**UPDATE**

See [this issue](http://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1023) and the related pull request for more details.

**UPDATE2**

It works for me with `ChatConnector`, using this code:

```js
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: '',
    appPassword: ''
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());


bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    if (!session.userData.TimeoutStarted) {
        session.send("I'll answer in 5 seconds");
        session.userData.TimeoutStarted = true;

        setTimeout(function() {
            session.send("Answer after 5 seconds");
            session.userData.TimeoutStarted = false;
        }, 5000);
    } else {
        session.send("Bot is busy");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your participating! I test it with ChatConnector and here is the same problem: it neither sends messages nor saves state inside the callback. But session could work with more then one send. So, for example, if I just receive the message and try sequence: session.send("a"); session.send("b"); - it works;

Comment: Are you sure? It works with me using ChatConnector, see my update. For the sequencing: I was not precise, but you can see the explanation in the GitHub issue. Basically, the session object does batching by default, i.e. it waits 250ms for additional messages before sending the current ones. That's why it works with your sequencing but it doesn't work if you wait 5000ms after the first message.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I test it again and you are absolutely right. It really works with ChatConnector. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For people who are interested in sending a delayed message from bot, you could use `session.delay(<ms>)`

For example,

```
session.send('msg')
session.delay(5000) // delay 5 seconds 
session.endDialog()
```