# Skype Bots. Timed messages. Does not require user input

Tags: c#, timer, skype, message, botframework

So I've recently been trying to make a skype bot that attempts to retrieve data from a website. Then blurt it out onto chat every 15 or so minutes and I do not require user input. Unfortunately, i can't seem to do this due to microsoft's lack of documentation on the bot framework.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.SimpleEchoBot
{
[Serializable]
public class EchoDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;
        await context.PostAsync("You said: " + message.Text);
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}

[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// receive a message from a user and send replies
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="activity"></param>
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {
        // check if activity is of type message
        if (activity != null && activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }

    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the Microsoft Open source Echobot for reference. How would i edit this to make a timed message every 15 minutes without the need of user input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to schedule tasks in Microsoft Bot Framework + C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431234/how-to-schedule-tasks-in-microsoft-bot-framework-c)