# Implement payment in Bot framework V4

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, chatbot

I want to implement payment in bot framework V4. I couldn't find any sample in c#. my main problem is after the payment page is open how to return back to the chat after the payment is done.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Channel you are using, For example in a **Facebook Messenger Webview** they provide you with an SDK so you can send/receive data between the Webview and the chat.

- In **Facebook Messenger** the webview can be opened directly inside
  the chat, when it's close you directly get back to the chat.
- In a **Twitter bot** once you close the Webview, you also get back to the chat. But i don't think they provide an SDK like Facebook from which you can know once the user is done.
- In the Direct Line Channel ( **WebChat** ) the default
  behavior will open a new tab so you can't really know from the bot once the payment is done in the new tab.

But in all cases you can provide the user with a payment URL containing data that can identify that user. Once the user completes the payment in that new web page, you can then trigger the bot to send a proactive message for the user on the chat and continue from there.

Comment: I am using Direct Line Channel ( WebChat ) and the question is after the payment in that new web page is done how to trigger the bot ?

Comment: There are many ways to do that, you could for example save the user id in a database with a flag that this user has reached this specific point, once that is flag is reached using Hangfire trigger a conversation, check this answer here it might guide you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431234/how-to-schedule-tasks-in-microsoft-bot-framework-c/38435130